# Convolutional operation: weighted average

Tags: calculus, convolution

I'm reading the book "[Deep Learning by Ian Fellow](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html)".

At chapter 9, page 327, there is the following formula:

$$s(t)=\int x(a)\omega (t-a)da$$

This operation is called **convolution**, and they explain it that we apply a weight, $\omega(a)$, to a value $x(a)$ at every moment.

I don't understand why they subtract $a$ from $t$ in $\omega(t-a)$.

Why they subtract $a$ from $t$?

Comment: Note that the convolution is symmetric, so it does not matter if you take $x(a)\omega(t-a)$ or $x(t-a)\omega(a)$.

Comment: @C.Hamster Thanks, but I don't understand why they do the subtraction. Why they subtract $a$ from $t$?  Shouldn't it be just $\omega(a)$?

Comment: Well, in that case the answer `because that is the definition of the convolution' probably won't help you either. The idea is that you are shifting the function $\omega$. You want to compute the average for every shifted version of $\omega$ in order to compute the average at every moment in time, and a shift to the right by $a$ given by $\omega(t-a)$.

Comment: I suggest to visit this related question: [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352961/understanding-the-convolution-as-a-weighted-average-to-eliminate-noise-st/3784495#3784495)